# Divergence interpretation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, terminology, distance

I'am getting familiar with the statistical notion of Divergence. The word "divergence" is also used in physics (or vector analysis, see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence). As I was more familiar with the second use, I wonder If there is a link between the two uses.

There seems to be none because the first one is a local volume variation in a flow and the second seems to reflect the difference between two distribution. But I cannot convince me there is no link between all these integrals. Can you help me ? Should I understand "divergence" in probability only as "difference" ?

Comment: Divergence in physics is merely a 3D version of a derivative, while in stats it is a *total* difference between distributions. Apart from sort of similar premise (both are kind of differences between some things), I don't see any connection.

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

Divergence in physics is merely a 3D version of a derivative, while in stats it is a total difference between distributions. Apart from sort of similar premise (both are kind of differences between some things), I don't see any connection. – sashkello
(and I don't see any connection either)